# Sorting a partially sorted array in O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Hey so I'm just really stuck on this question.

I need to devise an algorithm (no need for code) that sorts a certain partially sorted array into a fully sorted array. The array has N **real numbers** and the first N-[N\sqrt(N)] (the [] denotes the *floor* of this number) elements are sorted, while are the rest are not. There are no special properties to the unsorted numbers at the end, in fact I'm told nothing about them other than they're obviously real numbers like the rest.

The kicker is time complexity for the algorithm needs to be O(n).

My first thought was to try and sort only the unsorted numbers and then use a merge algorithm, but I can't figure out any sorting algorithm that would work here in O(n). So I'm thinking about this all wrong, any ideas?

Comment: What's the meaning of `N\sqrt(N)`? Is it N divided by the square root of N? (But why not simply saying square root N in this case)? If it is N times square root of N it would be higher than N so the question would not make sense.

Comment: It's N divided by the square root of N. There was a mistake in my original post, the first N-[N\sqrt(N)] elements are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the general case using a comparison-based sorting algorithm. You are most likely missing something from the question.

Imagine the partially sorted array `[1, 2, 3, 4564, 8481, 448788, 145, 86411, 23477]`. It contains 9 elements, the first 3 of which are sorted (note that `floor(N/sqrt(N)) = floor(sqrt(N))` assuming you meant `N/sqrt(N)`, and `floor(sqrt(9)) = 3`). The problem is that the unsorted elements are all in a range that does not contain the sorted elements. It makes the sorted part of the array useless to any sorting algorithm, since they will stay there anyway (or be moved to the very end in the case where they are greater than the unsorted elements).

With this kind of input, you still need to sort, independently, `N - floor(sqrt(N))` elements. And as far as I know, `N - floor(sqrt(N)) ~ N` (the `~` basically means "is the same complexity as"). So you are left with an array of approximately `N` elements to sort, which takes `O(N log N)` time in the general case.

Now, I specified "using a comparison-based sorting algorithm", because sorting real numbers (*in some range*, like the usual floating-point numbers stored in computers) can be done in amortized `O(N)` time using a hash sort (similar to a counting sort), or maybe even a modified radix sort if done properly. But the fact that a part of the array is already sorted doesn't help.

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken! The question is quite confusing to me. There are N-[N\sqrt(N)] sorted elements. In your example of N=9, the first 6 elements would be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, this means there are sqrt(N) unsorted elements at the end of the array. You can sort them with an O(n^2) algorithm which will give a time of O(sqrt(N)^2) = O(N); then do the merge you mentioned which will also run in O(N). Both steps together will therefore take just O(N).